# How to echo a php variable into html textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have the following problem. I want to echo a php variable in a html textarea. But i cant get it to work out for me. Here is my code.

```
<?php

$y = 123

?>

<textarea name="delay" cols="50"rows="5" id="delay">
<?php echo $y ?>
</textarea>
```

Here is what I see

[image]

Comment: Is that a .php page? you have to install/enable php.

Comment: No, its a .html file. I installed php5 with apt-get. How do i enable php on this file?

Comment: change the file extension to .php

Comment: just rename your file...it should be `.php` instead of `.html`..

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Lal, hairmot and Federkun

Comment: If this is solved, please tick the icon on the answer below that was most helpful. We don't  use [solved] title edits here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an easy way could be:

```
<?php

$y = 123;

echo "<textarea title='textarea' name='delay' cols='50' rows='5' id='delay'>".$y."</textarea>";

?>
```

also between `cols="50"rows="5"` should be an blankspace. like: `cols="50" rows="5"`